# @SuppressWarnings for final type parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, suppress-warnings

In a place I have a method with a generic "VT extends String". Obviously this generates a warning: *The type parameter VT should not be bounded by the final type String. Final types cannot be further extended*.

Do you know if there's a way to suppress this warning (Eclipse)? If you're wondering how I got to have this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A<T> {
T value;
B<? super T> b;

void method() {
    b.method(value,new ArrayList<T>());
}}

interface B<X> {
<VT extends X> VT method(VT p, List<VT> lst);
}

// works fine
class C implements B<Number> {
public <VT extends Number> VT method(final VT p, final List<VT> lst) {
    return p;
}}

// causes warning
class D implements B<String> {
public <VT extends String> VT method(final VT p, final List<VT> lst) {
    return p;
}}

// error: The type E must implement the inherited abstract method B<String>.method(VT, List<VT>)
class E implements B<String> {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String method(final String p, final List<String> lst) {
    return p;
}}
```

Comment: I guess the only way to supress the warning is `@SuppressWarnings("all")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, but here's something similar, which I assume is what you want:

```
class A<T>{
    T value;
    B<? super T> b;
    void method(){
        b.method(value);
    }
}
interface B<X>{
    <VT extends X> VT method(VT p);
}
// works fine
class C implements B<Number>{
    public <VT extends Number> VT method(VT p){return p;}
}
// causes warning
class D implements B<String>{
    public <VT extends String> VT method(VT p){return p;}
}
```

Seeing that you don't have a choice to saying `extends String` here, I'd say this is a bug in Eclipse. Furthermore, Eclipse can usually suggest an appropriate `SuppressWarnings`, but doesn't here. (Another bug?)

What you can do is change the return and argument type to `String` and then suppress the (irrelevant) type safety warning it causes:

```
// no warnings
class D implements B<String>{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String method(String p){return p;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for non-compile. I just fast-adapted it from my code. The return type in B,C,D should be void, but this does not affect my situation. Your solution is interesting and I would use it but it doesn't seem to work. If I do this I will get the error: "D does not implement method". Seems such a method does not have the same signature.

Comment: Actually it compiles just fine. My bad in explaining my code. I have 2 parameters to the method. That's when it fails. http://pastebin.com/RETLMnCj

Comment: Can you update your code in the original question so that it compiles and works like your situation? Still, the type parameter to `B.method` is pointless here (it would only make sense if you were expecting to return a value of the same type as the argument). You could just say `void method(X x)` in `B`. I'd recommend you to remove the type parameters to `method` if you control that code, rather than doing weird warning suppressions.

Comment: OK, looking at the pastebin code, I'd recommend you to give `method` the signature `void method(X x, List<? extends X> lst)` - no warnings, no compile errors, easier on the eyes.

Comment: Yet another reason to move to Intellij!