# Generics methods in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

My question is: is it possible to make one generic method where I can use 2 different types? E.g. an Integer and a String.

There is no practical use for this, but I'd just like to know if it's possible. And if it is, how? :)

Comment: What part of the methods would the generic type affect (arguments, return value, something else)?

Comment: do you mean something like `V put(K key, V value)` in [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a look into `java.util.Map`

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Which is most suitable depends on the context.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a method such as `<T> foo(T t)`, where `T` can be either a String or an Integer?

Comment: Do you mean that argument can be String or Integer but no other type, and violations are discovered at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use generics for this. You can overload the methods. For example

```
public void method(Integer i){}

public void method(String s){}
```

If you call method with an integer then it will call the first method. If you call it with a string it will call the second method.

Comment: @brimborium, I do not think its missing the point. It could sovle the problem. For those specific types. I think that this perspective is good one.

Comment: @Vash OP stated that he thinks there is no practical use for this. He just wants to know if it is possible using generics.

Comment: @brimborium there is no (practical or useful) way to do that with generics. Using overloaded methods __is the best way__ (IMO) to do stuff like this. The OP or anybody looking for an answer might not be aware of this so it's worth pointing it out, so I'd say this answer is quite on target!

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Ok, so the answer should have been: "No, but here is a different approach for it: [...]". If somebody asks you how to catch a fish with your bare hands, you don't explain to him how to do it with a fishing rod. At least not before telling how he would do it with his bare hands and why that is a bad/ineffective/expensive/timeconsuming/whatever/suboptimal approach.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean two different types of parameter?

You could use one method for the String param, and another than takes the integer and passes it on to the String version.

Answer (score 1):

The example types are not good one as the are final. This mean that you can not use them to limit the generic parameter as nothing can inherit from them.

So for that types the answer is No.

But what we can do with Java is:

You can create a method that accept Object type.

```
 public <T> void doStaff(T obj) {

 }
```

You can create a method that is limited to CharSequence as String is final

```
 public <T extends CharSequence> void doStaff(T str){ 

 }
```

You can create a method that is litmited to more the one interface

```
public <T extends CharSequence & Comparable<T>> void doStaf(T interf) {

}
```

But even with so many possibilities we can not create a generic parameter that is valid for Two unrelated types. This would not have sense. As main task of generic type is to provide type safety. And in generally when we use them we should operate with interfaces not classes.

Comment: I don't think the last example is valid Java code. What would it do? How can you work with a type that is either of type One or Two? Only an `&` makes really sense here...

Comment: As far as I can tell, Comparable seems to be an interface, so it is not extended, it's implemented ;-)

Comment: @tehlexx, yeah that was w typo cause lack of morning coffe fiex after posting.

Comment: @santirivera92, Interfaces can be extended by interfaces and implemented by classes.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about interfaces extending other interfaces. However I've never stumbled upon a situation where I wanted to extend an interface.

Comment: @santirivera92, Serializable or Comparable<T> are ofter inherited ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to accept Integer and String, try below approach:

```
  public class Test {
public static void main(String[] a)  {
    method(new String(),new Integer("2"));
}
public static <T extends String, U extends Integer> void  method(T t, U u){

}
}
```

EDIT:

if you want your method to take a single parameter that takes either a String or Integer

try this :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void  method(T t){

}
```

Comment: You can not extends from String or Integer, their are final Type.

Comment: @Vash although you extending String or integer is not possible, it works in the case of generics. the above code would compile. :)

Comment: Waht JVM you are using ? For sure on 5 and 6 will not compile.

Comment: @Vash did you try compiling the code ?? and my JVM version is 1.6.0_23

Comment: @Vash it would give you the below warning, not error ,..  The type parameter U should not be bounded by the final type Integer. Final types cannot be further 
  extended
 - The type parameter T should not be bounded by the final type String. Final types cannot be further 
  extended

Comment: That depend on your complier settings that this is and error or warning or none. As this operation do not have sense from my point of view is and error. Then complier will be able to process the code but from desing point of view this is invalid.

Comment: @Vash please refer to this question here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475050/why-t-extends-string-is-allowed-but-gives-warning :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19275/discussion-between-vash-and-gangnamstyleoverflowerror)

Comment: Well, the thing is, I only want to give 1 parameter that only can be an Integer or a String.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR, tnx! I figured this out. But what to do when I want to exclude e.g. Double? You're very helpful! :)

Comment: @Vash not to be rude but, earlier to our discussion yesterday about generics. please check this example on oracle site http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html please check the declaration of te class NaturalNumber .

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR, You are not beeing rude ;-). Please note that in the same page you also have example where `new Integer(10)` is used. So IMHO is not just very old. And also we can not exclude the theory that programmer do not know about that warining. ;-). But nice catch with that article  I must admit.