# how type variable allowing wrong type?

Tags: java, object, generics, upperbound, type-variables

```
package org.my.java;

public class TestTypeVariable {

    static <T,A extends T> void typeVarType(T t, A a){
        System.out.println(a.getClass());
        System.out.println(t.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String[] s){
        int i= 1;
        typeVarType("string", i);
    }
}
```

when run, following is the output :

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.String
```

How can `A` be of type `Integer` when it has been already upper-bounded to `String`?

Please explain me on it.

Comment: I cannot compile your example: 

Bound mismatch: The generic method typeVarType(T, A) of type TestTypeVariable is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer). The inferred type Integer is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <A extends T>

Which is what I would expect. Did you compile the source successfully?

Comment: With the compiler resolving `T` to `Object` and `A` to `Integer`, there is no issue.

Comment: @SilverNak It passes compilation in Java 8, but not in Java 7.

Comment: This is already being answered in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475050/why-t-extends-string-is-allowed-but-gives-warning

Answer (score 15):

Two things here:

- there is a simple solution to the "bad" typing: T isn't String but *Object*. And *Integer* extends Object. But please note: this only works with the "enhanced" type inference capabilities of Java8. With Java7, your input will not compile!
- misconception on your end: `getClass()` happens at **runtime**, and therefore returns the specific class of the objects passed - independent on what the compiler thinks about generics at compile time.

Comment: It compiles fine. `typeVarType("string", i);` has `T=Object, A=Integer` .

Comment: it is compilable and runable. getClass() i just used to print run-time type of an object.but thats not an issue. main point is how java allowing integer type for an string upper bounded type

Comment: @khelwood That happens when one believes in other comments without further checking. I thought "T should be Object" myself ... thanks, and updated.

Comment: It compiles fine in Java 8, but doesn't pass compilation in Java 7. In this case I think it makes more sense for it not to pass compilation, since `<T,A extends T>` makes no sense (due to type erasure).

Comment: Of course, the inferred type for `T` could also be `Object & Serializable & Comparable<?>`…

Comment: I wish you could quote the JLS here, i swear given this on an interview I would say it fails