# String cannot be converted to T

Tags: java, generics

Why does this result in a compilation error, despite that T extends String

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      Vehicle car = new  Vehicle<String>();
      System.out.println(car.getLicensePlate());
    }
}



class Vehicle<T extends String> {
     public T getLicensePlate() {
        String y="AB1234";
        return y;
    }
}
```

results in :

> Main.java:22: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to
>   T
>           return y;
>                    where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends String declared in class Vehicle 1 error

Comment: Note that `String` cannot be extended, it is a `final` class .

Comment: Even if I replace Vehicle<T extends String> with Vehicle<T> I get "String cannot be converted to T"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why \`T extends String\` is allowed but gives warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475050/why-t-extends-string-is-allowed-but-gives-warning)

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do here?

Comment: "A dog is a type of animal" doesn't mean the same as "all animals are dogs".

Comment: Of course "if you [use] `Vehicle<T>`", you cannot convert `String` to `T`, how would it be converted? Just return a `String` in `getLicensePlate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `String` is a final class, so `T extends String` makes no sense.

Second of all, even if you used a non-final class instead of `String` in the generic type bound, returning an instance of class X from a method having a return type that may extend X is not possible.

For example, if you changed your class to:

```
class Vehicle<T extends Animal>
```

The following wouldn't be valid:

```
 public T getAnimal() {
    return new Animal();
}
```

since `T` may be a sub-class of `Animal`, so if you instantiate your class with:

```
Vehicle<Cat> v = new Vehicle<>();
```

a call to `v.getAnimal()` must return a `Cat` instance, not an `Animal` instance.

Comment: I'd add a diamond operator to `new Vehicle()` or you'll get a warning again.